# Can I share colors, bombs, contacts between Android and iOS devices?

Tags: draw-something

I've got an iPod touch which I'd like to install the app on, but I use *Draw Something* on my Samsung Galaxy S II with the paid version.

Will I lose colours, bombs, or contacts in changing devices between platforms?

Comment: @BenBrocka Note that that one deals with Draw Something on more than one device with iOS, whereas this one is also cross-platform(android and iOS). It can probably be modified to address this case but as it stands this is slightly different.

Comment: @Mana Alright, that doesn't seem like a total dupe then. Can't rescind my vote though

Answer (score 6):

All the stuff you've unlocked is tied to your account and not to a device.  (Experience from playing on multiple devices.)